How do you size, resize, and align the contents of a CTabCtrl?
Given a dialog as follows, containing a CTabCtrl, what steps are required to determine the rectangle of the CTabCtrl, so that a dialog can be placed inside the tab?

I have tried two different ways to calculate the boundaries of the dialogs, but I cannot get the top and left to line up. Most specifically, the dialog inserted is too far up and to the left, perhaps suggesting that padding is included in the calculation.
The docs for this a too vague to be useful, things like "bounding rectangle" are mentioned but nowhere defined. Does the box describe the inside? The outside? The drop shadow? No idea.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ctabctrl-class?view=msvc-170#getitemrect
The two code attempts are as follows:
void CMyMFCDlg::ResizeTab()
{
#if 1

    RECT rect;

    // Get size of dialog window.
    m_ctlTab.GetClientRect(&rect);

    // Adjust the rectangle to fit the tab control into the
    // dialog's client rectangle.
    m_ctlTab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rect);

    // Move the tab control to the new position and size.
    for (std::shared_ptr<SignPage>& m_dlg : m_dlgs) {
        m_dlg->MoveWindow(&rect, FALSE);
    }
#endif

#if 0

    CRect tabRect, itemRect;

    m_ctlTab.GetClientRect(&tabRect);
    m_ctlTab.GetItemRect(m_ctlTab.GetCurSel(), &itemRect);

    int x, y, xc, yc;

    x = itemRect.left;
    y = itemRect.bottom + 1;
    xc = tabRect.right - itemRect.left - 1;
    yc = tabRect.bottom - y - 1;

    //  m_ctlTab.AdjustRect(FALSE, &rect);


    for (std::shared_ptr<SignPage>& m_dlg : m_dlgs) {
        m_dlg->ModifyStyle(WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_DISABLED
            | WS_THICKFRAME, WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CHILD | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS);
        m_dlg->SetWindowPos(&wndTop, x, y, xc, yc, 0);
    }

#endif

}

void CMyMFCDlg::OnSizing(UINT fwSide, LPRECT pRect)
{
    CDialogEx::OnSizing(fwSide, pRect);

    ResizeTab();

}

The question is, how do I determine the correct CRect corresponding to the area described by the arrows, in such a way that I can apply that CRect to the embedded dialogs for each tab?
Must I use SetWindowPos(), or MoveWindow(), and how is the rectangle passed to these methods calculated?
(I considered a PropertySheet but could not find a way to control the buttons below the dialog.)

Why don't you set up the dynamic resizing properties in the IDE to stretch the control as needed?

Have a look at the Win32 control documentation. It does a good job explaining the control basics.

@AndrewTruckle Resizing doesn't appear to be a problem, the dialog inside the tab is the correct size and stays the correct size throughout the resize process. The problem is it doesn't have the correct top and left coordinates, which are too far up and too far to the left (top left arrow in the diagram above) for reasons I do not understand.

@IInspectable I had already gone through the control docs, alas they tell you it's possible, but not specifically how. The docs are full of weasel words like "bounding box", bounding what, precisely?

In 2024, it makes little sense to still use CTabCtrl. My recommendation is for you to use CMFCTabCtrl. Way easier, and you don't even have to handle the components show/hide logic when cycling among the tabs.

@sergiol Alas I tried CMFCTabCtrl originally, however it's not supported by Visual Studio 2022 resource files. The docs make no mention of how you'd instantiate them in a resource file. Looking for existing projects on Github as examples, all of them seem to be creating a CTabCtrl, then querying its dimensions, deleting it, and programmatically creating CMFCTabCtrl, which is super weird.

@GrahamLeggett: You don't need to programmatically delete and recreate it. IIRC you only need to have a control in the resource file, and then associate it in the line you create it.
